# max query store size in sql database getting reverted

Tags: azure-sql-database, sql-query-store

I used below query to increase max query store size:

```
> ALTER DATABASE [QueryStoreDB] SET QUERY_STORE (MAX_STORAGE_SIZE_MB = 1024);
```

But after SQL DevOps deployment, it was getting reverted to default 100 MB.

How to keep it always at 1000 MB and stop getting reverted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to open SQL project in Visual Studio.
2. Right-click on project and select 'properties'.
3. Click on database settings as shown below:
   [image]
4. In 'operational', you need to tweak the 'Max Storage Size (MB)' value from 100 to 1000.
   [image]
5. Save Project and commit .sqlproj file.
6. You would see new line like below added to your .sqlproj:
   [image]

Comment: Presumably you want the Operational mode set to something other than Off as well, otherwise Query Store isn't going to record *anything*.